# Excel - Autofill cells based on previous matches

Tags: excel, unique, autofill

I'm trying to make an expense tracker spreadsheet that automatically assigns a value to a cell in the column **Category** as I type in the cell  of the column **Description**. This "autofill" (technically might be called something else) will be based on values of **Category** that  have been previously typed in that match the **Description**.

To ilustrate, here's my current table:

| Description (typed in) | Amount (typed in) | Category (typed in ONCE per unique Description value) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Waldo's Market | $ 30 | Groceries |
| Benny's Petrol | $ 50 | Gas |
| Matt's Burgers | $ 7 | Snacks |

As I type in the next **Description**, I want Excel to automatically fill **Category** as such:

| Description | Amount | Category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Waldo's Market | $ 30 | Groceries |
| Benny's Petrol | $ 50 | Gas |
| Matt's Burgers | $ 7 | Snacks |
| Waldo's Market **(typed in)** | $ 8 **(typed in)** | Groceries **(autofilled)** |

I've tried a workaround using Excel's `UNIQUE` function to dump all unique values of the column **Description** to a new tab, assigning a **Category** to each one of them in that tab and then using the `INDEX and MATCH` method to fill the column **Category** in the original tab, but as soon as I type in a new unique value in the original **Description** column, the values of the `UNIQUE` list shift and the match gets messed.

Comment: Please show us exactly what you tried.

Comment: You do not need `UNIQUE()`. Use just `XLOOKUP()` function.